# Change value of variable in Nuxt 3 with vue.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Im really new to Nuxt 3 and Vue 3.
I just want simple value change when i click on my div tag.

```
<a id="change" @click="changeValue()">{{value}}</a>
```

```
<script  lang="ts" setup>
let value = "Old";
function changeValue(){
  value="new"
}
</script>
```

This is the only thing i tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rap's answer is correct and that's how you do it using Options API.
To add, here's another way to do it using Composition API:

- You need to declare the `value` variable as a reactive variable using Ref().
  [Ref](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html#reactive-variables-with-ref) can hold any data type.
- To update the reactive variable, use the `.value` property.

```
<template>
  <div id="change" @click="changeValue">{{myValue}}</div>
</template>

<script setup>
const myValue = ref("Old");
function changeValue(){
  myValue.value = "new"
}
</script>
```

Note: I replaced the variable name `value` to `myValue` in the example above to avoid confusion with `.value` property.

For further reading, you can check out the [Reactivity in Vue](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/reactivity-in-depth.html#how-reactivity-works-in-vue).